# A word for surpassing/outdoing one's teacher/master?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What do you call someone (say, a student) who surpasses, or outdoes, his/her master or teacher, in skill or achievements?

I'm looking for a single word, preferably; if not, as succinct a phrase as possible.

Comment: There are a half-dozen excellent metaphors/idioms, but no single word is apt to do the concept justice.

Comment: Do you mean achieving a high degree of success at a very young age? Without an example sentence, as the tag info mandates, it's very hard to interpret your question. There are too many words that seem fit, given the .minimal context

Comment: @BiscuitBoy: No, young age is not implied, and the degree of success is only relative, not necessarily absolute.

Comment: Do you want a noun for the act of surpassing one's teacher, a noun that describes a person who surpasses his/her teacher, an adjective that describes a person who surpasses his/her teacher...? Please edit your question to add more information on how you want to use this word, such as an example sentence with a blank for the word. As BiscuitBoy says, it's part of this guidance for questions in this tag: http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info

Answer (score 5):

I would use [***eclipsing***](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/eclipse_2) or ***eclipsed***, pending on the tense.

> **eclipse somebody/something** to make somebody/something seem dull or unimportant by comparison

(Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary)

Comment: +1, there's also a variety of negative words like *supplant*, *usurp* and synonyms if replacement is part of the eclipsing.

Answer (score 2):

he overtook his teacher

he outshone her

his achievements exceeded hers

he overshadowed her

he put her in the shade

he shot past her

he ran rings round her

she talked about wings, he flew

she killed her thousands, he his tens of thousands

pupil-turned master

Comment: Nice allusion to David and Saul! Don

Answer (score 1):

Once a Student has “[surpassed the Teacher](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SurpassedTheTeacher),” they would seem to fit (except for the “fictional” part)  in *TV Tropes’* definition (although not listed in its examples) of  a **[superior successor](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SuperiorSuccessor)**:

> A fictional phenomenon where a younger generation, a younger sibling,
>   **or some other form of successor** proves to be smarter, more capable, or much more powerful than the preceding generation.

(both links to and above quote [with emphasis added] from ‘TV Tropes’)

Answer (score 0):

**The student has become the master**.

Though not a direct quote, this is commonly attributed to the original *Star Wars* film, when Darth Vader confronts Obi-Wan Kenobi before killing him:

> Darth Vader: When I left you, I was but the learner, now I am the master.

See the scene [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZD1f9RTEJU)

Comment: ... and you think this was original with *Star Wars*?